# Ubuntu 18.04 - iwlwifi fails

Tags: 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi

The wifi suddenly became unavailable on my computer. I don't understand why and I don't know how to reactivate it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some maybe useful log to understand the problem
`dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    5.759902] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

[    5.773568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.3235921300.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.814408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    6.055803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    6.055806] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    6.055863] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x240f
[    6.055865] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    6.068107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried the following without success

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you install newer firmware to see if it helps. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: I have the same problem, i followed your instructions, but it didnt help.

Here is the `dmesg | grep iwl` output

https://pastebin.com/g7306rVQ

Im running Ubuntu 20 though

Comment: @chai_and_kaapi I suggest that you start your own new question.